# Current perspectives on p-value computation in mixed effects models

Tags: mixed-model, p-value

I am interested in the latest insights and thinking about the computation of p-values for the fixed effects in mixed models. This stems from the perspective offered by Douglas Bates in 2006, where he expressed reservations about the methodological soundness of computing p-values at all for the fixed effects in mixed models due to the complexities inherent in these models, especially regarding the denominator degrees of freedom for $F$ statistics. In particular, he wrote, in 2006, on the R-Sig-ME mailing list:

> ### lmer, p-values and all that

> Users are often surprised and alarmed that the summary of a linear mixed model fit by `lmer` provides estimates of the fixed-effects parameters, standard errors for these parameters and a t-ratio but no p-values.  Similarly the output from `anova()` applied to a single `lmer` model provides the sequential sums of squares for the terms in the fixed-effects specification and the corresponding numerator degrees of freedom but no denominator degrees of freedom and, again, no p-values.

> Because they feel that the denominator degrees of freedom and the corresponding p-values can easily be calculated they conclude that failure to do this is a sign of inattention or, worse, incompetence on the part of the person who wrote `lmer` (i.e. me).

> Perhaps I can try again to explain why I don't quote p-values or, more to the point, why I do not take the "obviously correct" approach of attempting to reproduce the results provided by SAS.  Let me just say that, although there are those who feel that the purpose of the R Project - indeed the purpose of any statistical computing whatsoever - is to reproduce the p-values provided by `SAS`, I am not a member of that group.  If those people feel that I am a heretic for even suggesting that a p-value provided by `SAS` could be other than absolute truth and that I should be made to suffer a slow, painful death by
> being burned at the stake for my heresy, then I suppose that we will be able to look forward to an exciting finale to the conference dinner at UseR!2006 next month. (Well, I won't be looking forward to such a finale but the rest of you can.)

> As most of you know the t-statistic for a coefficient in the fixed-effects model matrix is the square root of an $F$ statistic with 1 numerator degree of freedom so we can, without loss of generality, concentrate on the F statistics that were present in the anova output.  Those who long ago took courses in "analysis of variance" or "experimental design" that concentrated on designs for agricultural experiments would have learned methods for estimating variance components based on observed and expected mean squares and methods of
> testing based on "error strata".  (If you weren't forced to learn this, consider yourself lucky.)  It is therefore natural to expect that the F statistics created from an `lmer` model (and also those created by `SAS PROC MIXED`) are based on error strata but that is not the case.

> The parameter estimates calculated by `lmer` are the maximum likelihood or the `REML` (residual maximum likelihood) estimates and they are not based on observed and expected mean squares or on error strata.  And that's a good thing because lmer can handle unbalanced designs with multiple nested or fully crossed or partially crossed grouping factors for the random effects.  This is important for analyzing data from large observational studies such as occur in psychometrics.

> There are many aspects of the formulation of the model and the calculation of the parameter estimates that are very interesting to me and have occupied my attention for several years but let's assume that the model has been specified, the data given and the parameter estimates obtained. How are the $F$ statistics calculated?  The sums of squares and degrees of freedom for the numerators are calculated as in a linear model.  There is a slot in an `lmer` model that is similar to the "effects" component in a `lm` model and that, along with the "assign" attribute for the model matrix provides the numerator of the $F$ ratio.  The denominator is the penalized residual sum of squares divided by the REML degrees of freedom, which is $n-p$ where $n$ is the number of observations and $p$ is the column rank of the model matrix for the fixed effects.

> Now read that last sentence again and pay particular attention to the word "the" in the phrase "the penalized residual sum of squares".  All the $F$ ratios use the same denominator.  Let me repeat that - all the $F$ ratios use the *same* denominator.  This is why I have a problem with the assumption (sometimes stated as more that just an assumption - something on the order of "absolute truth" again) that the reference distribution for these F statistics should be an F distribution with a known numerator degrees of freedom but a variable denominator degrees of freedom and we can answer the question of how to calculate a p-value by coming up with a formula to assign different denominator degrees of freedom for each test.  The denominator doesn't change. Why should the degrees of freedom for the denominator change?

> Most of the research on tests for the fixed-effects specification in a mixed model begin with the assumption that these statistics will have an $F$ distribution with a known numerator degrees of freedom and the only purpose of the research is to decide how to obtain an approximate denominator degrees of freedom.  I don't agree.

> There is one approach that I think may be fruitful and that I am currently pursuing. The penalized least squares formulation of a mixed-effects model shows that the residual sum of squares in actually a penalized residual sum of squares and there is a quantity that behaves like the degrees of freedom for a penalized least squares problem. I will insert code to calculate this and see how that behaves in simulation.

> For the time being, I would recommend using a Markov Chain Monte Carlo sample (function `mcmcsamp`) to evaluate the properties of individual coefficients (use `HPDinterval` or just summary from the "coda" package). Evaluating entire terms is more difficult but you can always calculate the F ratio and put a lower bound on the denominator degrees of freedom.

> If anyone wants to contribute code to calculate the "obviously correct" denominator degrees of freedom from `SAS` I will incorporate it.  However, be warned that the penalized least squares approach and sparse matrix methods used in `lmer` will require considerable translation from the formulas which typically occur in papers on this topic.  Generally those formulas involve the inverse of an $n \times n$ matrix where $n$ is the number of observations and you really, really don't want to try to do that when you have a couple of million observations.

Since then, the landscape of statistical computing and mixed models in R has evolved significantly. Packages like `lmerTest`, `glmmAdaptive`, `mmrm`, and `glmmTMB` have emerged, offering capabilities to compute p-values.

How has the community's view on the computation of p-values in mixed models evolved since Douglas Bates' initial reservations? Are there new methodological developments or consensus that might shed light on this topic? Did someone perhaps "*contribute code to calculate the "obviously correct" denominator degrees of freedom from `SAS`*"?

Bates has developed mixed models packages for Julia. Does anyone know if his stance on p-values has influenced his approach in these newer implementations?

How do the approaches of R packages like `glmmAdaptive`, `mmrm`, and `glmmTMB` in computing p-values compare with `lmerTest`? Do they address the challenges Bates outlined, particularly regarding the uniform denominator for F statistics and the penalized residual sum of squares?

Also, `nlme` (which I haven't really used that much) also seems to compute p-values and this is also co-authored by Bates. Given that "mainstream" software such as `SAS` and `SPSS` do provide p-values in their mixed models output, `lme4` seems to be the odd one out in the current landscape, and what are the implications for users who rely heavily on p-values for inferential statistics?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Very long question, but I'll take a crack at it.  The material in the [relevant section of the GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#why-doesnt-lme4-display-denominator-degrees-of-freedomp-values-what-other-options-do-i-have) is still reasonably accurate, as far as I know (feedback welcome!)

- `nlme::lme`: this package uses a "within-between" or parameter-counting approach, which is adequate for simpler model structures (single-term or nested models), but which gets progressively less applicable/harder for random-slopes models (see comments in the GLMM FAQ), crossed random effects, unbalanced designs, or more complex random effect structures where the random effects themselves are no longer iid
- `lme4::lmer`: in response to Doug Bates's comment (from the quote above) that

  > If anyone wants to contribute code to calculate the "obviously correct" denominator degrees of freedom from SAS I will incorporate it

  this *did happen* with the implementation of the `pbkrtest` package (`pbkr` = "Parametric bootstrap/Kenward-Roger") — although it was never "incorporated" directly in `lme4` as suggested ... This implementation is used in most downstream packages, including in particular `lmerTest` (which wraps `lme4::lmer` so that it automatically provides denominator df in output), as well as (e.g.) `emmeans` and other packages for computing model summaries. `lmerTest` also provides a *Satterthwaite* approximation (which is inherited by `emmeans` as well).
- `glmmTMB` provides only "infinite" ddf summaries (i.e. based on $\chi^2$/$Z$ statistics rather than $F$/$t$); discussion [here](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/536) and [here](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/350) eventually led to the development of the `mmrm` package
- The `mmrm` package provides within-between, Satterthwaite, and K-R ddfs for *one particular class* of LMMs (the authors implemented Satterthwaite and K-R from scratch: their [notes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mmrm/vignettes/kenward.html) are very thorough and might (?) be used as a starting point for implementing these procedures in `glmmTMB`, although these particular implementations rely on the fact that `mmrm` is fitting a special case/special class of LMMs)
- `GLMMadaptive::mixed_model()` does only (non-Gaussian) GLMMs; the theory for finite-size corrections is relatively poorly developed for GLMMs, most GLM(M) frameworks don't consider finite-size corrections (see comments in the GLMM FAQ)
- as far as I can see `MixedModels.jl` hasn't implemented finite-size corrections: see [this issue](https://github.com/JuliaStats/MixedModels.jl/issues/305)

A few other notes:

- one strike against Kenward-Roger is that in the general case it requires inverting an $n \times n$ matrix (where $n$ is the number of observations), making it impractical for large problems
- along with the finite-ddf problem, one should also consider the possible non-Normality of the confidence intervals (suggesting a profile CI rather than Wald CIs), and the dependence of the CIs on the uncertainty in the random effect variance estimates (suggesting profile CI or parametric bootstrap); these are problems that are *not* addressed by the various methods described here.
- One can also do some form of Markov chain Monte Carlo as suggested by Doug Bates (see e.g. `MCMCglmm`, `rstanarm`, `brms` packages); the big drawback here is that sampling with 'flat' priors that mimic the frequentist setup of the problem is going to lead to computational problems in exactly the same circumstances where we are interested in/concerned with finite-size corrections ... (one of the reasons Doug abandoned the `mcmcsamp` approach is that it can get in trouble when it approaches the boundaries of the space of positive-definite matrices)

---

Li, Peng, and David T. Redden. 2015. “Comparing Denominator Degrees of Freedom Approximations for the Generalized Linear Mixed Model in Analyzing Binary Outcome in Small Sample Cluster-Randomized Trials.” BMC Medical Research Methodology 15 (April): 38. https://doi.org/10.1186/s12874-015-0026-x.

Schaalje, G., J. McBride, and G. Fellingham. 2002. “Adequacy of Approximations to Distributions of Test Statistics in Complex Mixed Linear Models.” Journal of Agricultural, Biological & Environmental Statistics 7 (14): 512–24.

Stroup, W. W. 2013. “Non-Normal Data in Agricultural Experiments.” In . Kansas State University. http://newprairiepress.org/agstatconference/2013/proceedings/8.

Comment: Side note: Bayesian random effects model are easy to implement and to run, do not provide p-values (I see this as an advantage), and do not use approximations (have only simulation error if convergence diagnostics are good), and allow assesment of evidence for compound and non-null assertions.  Sometimes the approximations used with mixed effects frequentist modeling are not of sufficient accuracy, perhaps especially with large numbers of small clusters.

Comment: I think you mean nlme in your first bullet

Comment: This is great, thanks Ben, I will award a bounty for your hard work !!